Strong potential of MNAR issue - can we still use MI i.e., mice() in R?
Study goal: estimate the proportion of patients who experience outcome Y (1=Yes, 0=No) within max 5 years of follow-up.
Missing data issue: Outcome Y is missing for a large proportion of people (96% missing). For those we have observed Outcome Y data, most of them have the outcome (78% have Y=1) because we only verified outcome data on people we suspected experienced the outcome. This was done for efficiency reasons - in order to validate those with true Y, we had to sift through medical records which was very time consuming. We do not anticipate that the rest of the study population missing outcome Y has the same prevalence of outcome Y. In fact, we believe it is much, much lower - possibly 5-10%.
Question: Can we use the data we have to impute the outcome Y on the rest of the study population, given that we certainly have a missing not a random (MNAR) issue (i.e., the data are missing for reasons related to the values themselves)? We do have a lot of strong predictors of the outcome Y in our imputation  model and have the flags for suspected Y in the imputation model as well, so accounting for at least some of the missing data mechanism. But given just how different the expected % with outcome Y is in the unobserved sample (5-10%) vs. the observed sample (78%), I'm wary of using MI...

It seems that your missingness is clearly not missing at random (Only the people more likely to present Y=1 are followed up...). In general, imputation should be possible, however I would try it if I had a dataset with the characteristics that influence the output Y=1 or Y=0, and model this output as a function of the characteristics. Also, by the size of the missing data (96%) I would expect a lot of noise in your imputation (biased towards the observed values, Y=1). Bayesian Methods can be useful, both, to understand the noise level and to incorporate prior information around 5-10% ratio.

It is not crystal clear whether the problem is actually MNAR. If your selection is based on the outcome itself, then yes, missingness is MNAR. However, if your selection is based on the values for other variables that you thought were indicative of a high probability of having Y = 1, and these other variables are fully observed, you might still be dealing with a MAR scenario.
If the problem is actually MNAR, you could use imputation and perform a sensitivity analysis (see this chapter in the book Flexible imputation of missing data). Alternatively, you could use techniques specifically designed for MNAR missingness, such as Heckman's selection model (see here) or imputation-based solutions (see this paper for instance).
Either way, the fact that you have clear expectations on the missing data allows you to evaluate the quality of your solution against your expectation. That is, you can actually evaluate which solution makes sense substantively.

Thanks! This makes a lot of sense. The other variables indicative of having a high probability of Y=1 are not fully observed - some are but not all and there's a lot of nuances to the data (when are there not? lol). But maybe with enough variables indicative of missingness, we can get close..
